# DB connection failed when hosted by IIS

Tags: iis, identityserver4

My IdentityServer worked fine when selfhosted (Kestrel) but throws an error when hosted in IIS: "An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyTestIDS' on server '.'" and "Login failed for user '(my machine name)$'". I have a connection string defined in appsettings.json with a value "Server=.;Database=MyTestIDS;trusted_connection=True;" and it connects to a SQL Server on my local machine. As I mentioned before, it's been working fine selfhosted until now when I host in IIS. I checked my deployed code and the appsettings.json is there. Does the app still read configuration settings from appsettings.json under IIS? Or should I move it to somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have different appSettings for different environments?

Comment: Thanks sombrerogalaxy for asking. I have an appsettings.json and an appsettings.Development.json if that's what you are asking. I am currently running under Development environment variable value. I have the same connection string defined in both files.

Comment: I have figured out the issue - the format of the connection string. When slfe-hosting, I used "Server=.;Database=MyTestDB;trusted_connection=True;" and it worked just fine there. But under IIS, I have to change it to something like "Server=MyServer,MyPort;Database=MyTestDB;user id=MyUsrID;Password=MyPassword". Not sure why but now I am working fine.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to post and mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Jalpa. As I explained in my comment, I have figured out how to fix my issue but I am not complete sure why. So I decided not to make it an answer so I don't misled people. But now I am going to do what you asked me to - I will take my comment and make it an asswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue - the format of the connection string. When slfe-hosting, I used "Server=.;Database=MyTestDB;trusted_connection=True;" and it worked just fine there. But under IIS, I have to change it to something like "Server=MyServer,MyPort;Database=MyTestDB;user id=MyUsrID;Password=MyPassword". Now I am working fine.